# Run time error '1004' - Workbook protected

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I wrote this code to move a sheet from one workbook to another. It was working till yesterday and suddenly is throwing

```
Run time error '1004': Workbook is protected and cannot be changed
```

Following is the code. Debug is showing the last statement before `END SUB` to be the problem. Am not able to figure out whats wrong.

```
Sub copydata()
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
    Dim wbname As String

    ' check if the file is open (source file)
    ret = Isworkbookopen("C:\Users\Desktop\Scorecard\Write Offs.xlsx")
    If ret = False Then
        ' open file
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Scorecard\Write Offs.xlsx")
    Else
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks("Write Offs.xlsx")
    End If

    ' check if the file is open

    ret = Isworkbookopen("C:\Users\Desktop\Scorecard\Copy data from one excel to another.xlsm")
    If ret = False Then
        ' open file
        Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Scorecard\Copy data from one excel to another.xlsm")
    Else
        Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Copy data from one excel to another.xlsm")
    End If

    'Sheet to be copied from the PEH write off report
    Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("PEH WBB TOTAL MPG")
    shttocopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: if you manually open the workbook does it prompt for a password?  If so someone has protected the workbook which requires passwords to open now.

Comment: @xQbert: No there is no password.The file is in my system and nothing has changed since yesterday. I tried it for another worksheet from a different file and the same error keeps repeating.